# if statement & asterisk password breaking my program

Tags: c++, if-statement, and-operator

The purpose of the following code is to set up a pseudo movie database and be able to search through it with two queries.  The program itself worked until I also attempted to put a username and password into place (the password displaying on the screen with asterisks).  In order to use the username and password I set up an if statement such that if (username == "user" && password == "word") it would display "Hello, user".  Instead of the expected output, I was met with

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00cf3e36 in Movies.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.
```

The code is as follows

```
//global variables
char title [20], y, n;
int year;
string search;
//function 1
void sort_on_title(movies_iit films[], int n)
{
//Local struct variable used to swap records
movies_iit temp;    

for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
/*If s[i].title is later in alphabet than
s[i+1].title, swap the two records*/
        if(films[i].title>films[i+1].title)
            {
                temp = films[i];
                films[i] = films[i+1];
                films[i+1] = temp;
            }  
        }
    }
}
//end function 1
//function query1 prototype
void query1 (movies_iit movie);
//function query2 prototype
void query2 (movies_iit movie);
//function 2 prototype
void printmovie (movies_iit movie);
//beginning of main
int main ()
{
//login
//username: username
//password: password
string mystr;
int n;
char response;
string c[9];
string name;
cout << "enter your username "<<endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "enter your password "<<endl;
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
c[i] = getch();
printf ("*");
}

cout << "\n" << endl;

if (name == "username" && c[9] == "password")
    cout << "Welcome, user." << endl;
else
{cout << "###" <<  "unrecognized username/password combination" << "\t" << "please try again"     << "###" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
return 0;
    }
for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
{
    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
}
//sort records, function 1 call
sort_on_title(films, NUM_MOVIES);
cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++) 
    printmovie (films[n]);  //function 2 call
//Query 1
cout << "Perform an alphabetical search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;

if (response == 'y')
    {cout << "Please enter title" << endl;
    cin >> title;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {query1 (films[n]);
            response == n;
        }
    }
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "\n" << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
//Query 2
cout << "Perform a chronological search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;
//greater than
if (response == 'y')
{   cout << "greater than what year?" << endl;
    cin >> year;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {   query2 (films[n]);
        }
}
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "Thank you, goodbye." << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
//end of  main
//function 2 definition
void printmovie (movies_iit movie)
{
  cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
//function query1 defintion
void query1 (movies_iit movie)
{
  if (movie.title == title)
      {cout << " >> " << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
  else
      {cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
}
//function query2 definition
void query2 (movies_iit movie)
{
  if (movie.year >= year)
      {cout << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
      }
}
```

How can I get my program to run properly?
*if it matters, the program ran properly before I added the code for the username & password and the if statement

posted below is the original version (the one that runs)

```
// array of structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_MOVIES 6
//structure
struct movies_iit{
    string title;
    int year;
} films [NUM_MOVIES];
//global variables
char title [20], y, n;
int year;
string search;
//function 1
void sort_on_title(movies_iit films[], int n)
{
//Local struct variable used to swap records
movies_iit temp;    

for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
/*If s[i].title is later in alphabet than
s[i+1].title, swap the two records*/
        if(films[i].title>films[i+1].title)
            {
                temp = films[i];
                films[i] = films[i+1];
                films[i+1] = temp;
            }  
        }
    }
}
//end function 1
//function query1 prototype
void query1 (movies_iit movie);
//function query2 prototype
void query2 (movies_iit movie);
//function 2 prototype
void printmovie (movies_iit movie);
//beginning of main
int main ()
{
//login
//username: user
//password: word
string mystr;
int n;
char response;
string c[4];
string name;
for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
{
    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
}
//sort records, function 1 call
sort_on_title(films, NUM_MOVIES);
cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++) 
    printmovie (films[n]);  //function 2 call
//Query 1
cout << "Perform an alphabetical search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;

if (response == 'y')
    {cout << "Please enter title" << endl;
    cin >> title;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {query1 (films[n]);
            response == n;
        }
    }
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "\n" << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
//Query 2
cout << "Perform a chronological search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;
//greater than
if (response == 'y')
{   cout << "greater than what year?" << endl;
    cin >> year;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {   query2 (films[n]);
        }
}
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "Thank you, goodbye." << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
//end of  main
//function 2 definition
void printmovie (movies_iit movie)
{
  cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
//function query1 defintion
void query1 (movies_iit movie)
{
  if (movie.title == title)
      {cout << " >> " << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
  else
      {cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
}
//function query2 definition
vvoid query2 (movies_iit movie)
    {
  if (movie.year >= year)
      {cout << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
      }
}
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help with this if this code either compiled, or was formatted reasonable (or both!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `string` with the operations for `char *`. You do not need an array of `string` just to store a password, just read it as you do with the name. If you want to read the password using `getch` for the `*` thing, read into a `char[9]` and then convert to `string` (only 1 string).

And BTW, `c[9]` does not exist, what are you trying to do with it?

BTW 2: If you read 9 chars into a `char[9]` and you don't set the last position to `0`, bad things will happen when you try to use any string-related function (not to mention that `"password"` has a length of 8 so it cannot match).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line, and all the lines in which you use the same convention, without understanding it:

```
string c[9];
```

The above doesn't mean "string with max 9 characters", it means "an array of 9 strings with as many characters as you input". In the loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
   c[i] = getch();
}
```

you input 1 character in EVERY string (not 9 characters in one string). Then, when you try to compare `c[9]` with "password", the program tries to access elements of `c[9]` which don't exist.